# Bool Tool Fast Solver

Tags: python

When I select a few objects and use the Bool Tool union, it is not uncommon that one of my objects disappears. I am looking for a script which will rather select the FAST Bool Tool with a Solver option of 0.
So, the script is this:

bpy.ops.object.booltool_auto_union()

Just need to make sure it goes to the previous Blender fast Boolean.

Comment: you can find the old verson of this addon, and install to the new verson blander

Comment: I only want a script to rather select the "Fast" and not the "Exact".

Answer (score 1):

**Go to the addon file location:**

[image]

[image]

**Copy the py file to desktop or other place.

Open with Notepad or other editor**

[image]

**Find the text: def boolean_mod**

[image]

**Add text between line 575 and 576**

```
md.solver = 'FAST'
```

[image]

**Save and replace the original**

[image]

**It will use the fast algorithm when apply the modifiers in this operator.**

Comment: Thank you, this is a good solution for myself, however too difficult for the lay person who's only willing to push one button in a script.